# SQL Server - Order of Execution / AFTER TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I would like to know what the time delay is between the execution of a statement and the firing of the first AFTER trigger. I am going to be doing a simple update of a datetime2 field after a query has completed for concurrency reasons. INSTEAD OF triggers would have been my first choice, but SELECT INTO is not available for SQL Azure.

I'm looking to find out if it would be possible to retrieve a row before the AFTER triggers begin their execution, and if so what is the chance of this happening under heavy load?

Comment: As the row is still not committed at that point, I doubt another transaction would be able to see it.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a delay as such. The trigger is part of the transaction/statement.

Also, you have the INSERTED and DELETED special tables that contain the changed data: no need to query the actual table in a trigger

Edit

Finally, if there is a default on the column then you can use this

```
UPDATE
   SomeTable
SET
   foo = ...,
   bar = ...,
   TheDateTime2Column = DEFAULT -- this
WHERE
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined delay, but if you are calling GETDATE() in two places you are probably going to get different results, sooner or later, depending on the hardware, the volume of data and the complexity of the triggers.

To make sure you are not reading dirty or inconsistent data, you should use transaction isolation levels wisely, according to the types of data access that you need.